# How would you generate a key that is only valid for three months?

Tags: security, language-agnostic, encryption, hash, key

I am wondering if it is possible to generate a "key" that is valid for a period of (approximately) three months?

For example, let's say (hypothetically) that I generate a key like this (pseudocode):

```
Key = HASH ( MachineID, Salt );
```

And the way I verify a key is valid is to check like this:

```
isValid(Key)
{
   return Key == HASH ( MachineID, Salt )
}
```

How would you extend this to generate a key like this:

```
Key = HASH ( MachineID, Salt, LastMonth, ThisMonth, NextMonth );
```

But still have your isValid work correctly?

One way I can see is:

```
isValid(Key)
{
   return Key == HASH ( MachineID, Salt, (LastMonth), (ThisMonth), (NextMonth) )
   || Key == HASH ( MachineID, Salt, (LastMonth-1), (LastMonth), (ThisMonth) )
   || Key == HASH ( MachineID, Salt, (ThisMonth), (ThisMonth+1), (ThisMonth+2) )
}
```

But I would like to know if any better ideas come to mind.

Comment: The quick answer: This is impossible.
The detailed answer is: It strongly depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Is this for authentication, cryptography, or something else?  With a specific problem/use-case, we may be able to propose a working solution.

Comment: @Eadwacer - authentication but it was more the abstract problem, I have no particular need right now.

Comment: Note that you should be using `HMAC()` where you have `HASH()`.

Comment: @caf hash is pseudocode, but thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A typical way of doing this is to compose a cleartext message explaining what is needed to reach the key, which is then followed by the secure digest.  You would thus return something like

```
function Key(password, expriry) {
    return "Expires: " + dateformat(expiry) +
           HASH(salt + expiry + password)
}
```

Note that the returned key contains the expiration date in clear text, but also includes it in the digest so that it cannot be tampered with.  As always, it's not necessary to decode the digest, only verify that the same inputs produced the same digest.

Comment: Thanks, but this requires the end application to know the expiry date. Is there any way for the end application to do a "here is today's date" is that valid for this key? Edit: Having reviewed, I see the solution is to make sure the user types in the expiry as well. It's a solution but I'm still curious if there's a better way.

Comment: @Graphain: Well, the idea is to encode the expiry date into the "key" - you can always encode the expiry date as a couple of bytes (two bytes is enough for 180 years worth of days!), so the "key" is just lengthened by two bytes and the user has no idea that part of it is a date.

Comment: @caf, yes but when decoding I do not know the expiry date, just the current date and I was hoping there was a method that the key could only be decrypted if the current date is less than the expiry date.

Comment: @Graphain: When decoding you extract the expiry date from the composite key.

Comment: @caf - Yeah I get that and it's probably the best way.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a unix timestamp, and then cut it in a number of bits that makes it have a precision of about 3 months.

For example:
1275068416 ( Fri, 28 May 2010 17:40:16 GMT )

is equal to:

**010011000** 00000000000000000000000

If we save 9 bits of that in the hash, and the 9th bit change:

**010011001** 00000000000000000000000

it will be equal to:
1283457024 ( Thu, 02 Sep 2010 19:50:24 GMT )

The difference is:
97 days, 2 hours, 10 minutes, 8 seconds

Which is 7 days more than 3 months.

Lets say the 9th bit change again (in a forward direction):

**010011010** 00000000000000000000000

is equal to: 1291845632 ( Wed, 08 Dec 2010 22:00:32 GMT )
which has a difference of:
97 days, 3 hours, 10 minutes, 8 seconds from 1283457024 ( Thu, 02 Sep 2010 19:50:24 GMT ).

So try it out, save the 9 first bits of a strictly 32bit unix timestamp in the hash, and you will get a validity of three months. Note that the validity is in blocks of three months, so if you generate a key in the end of a three month period, (lets say Tue, 07 Dec 2010 22:00:32 GMT) it will only be valid in a shorter time.